# Prove that $\sqrt[n]{x}-1 \le \frac{x-1}{n}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

how do you prove this inequality? $\sqrt[n]{x}-1 \le \frac{x-1}{n}$

It looks to me as if Bernoulli's inequality would be useful.

How about the following $\frac{x-1}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{x}-1$ From here on out I would have to show that the left hand side is $\geq (1+x)^n$ and that the right hand side $\le 1+nx$

Problem is that I don't know how to do that. Can someone help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$\sqrt[n]{x}-1 \le \frac{x-1}{n}\iff \sqrt[n]{x} \le \frac{x+n-1}n$$

then by AM-GM

$$\frac{x+\overbrace{1+\ldots+1}^{n-1\,terms}}n\ge...$$

Comment: Ah alright I think I see what you mean. $$\frac{x+\overbrace{1+\ldots+1}^{n-1\,terms}}n\ge \frac{x}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{x}$$

Comment: The problem is that I only know AM-GM for $$\frac{x+y}{2} \ge \sqrt[2]{xy}$$ Is $$\frac{x+y}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{xy}$$ Correct as well?

Comment: @D.John We just need to apply the AM-GM inequality. What is the intermediate step? Note that on the LHS we have the AM of $n$ terms, one x nad $n-1$ ones.

Comment: @D.John The general statement is $$\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2...x_n}$$

Comment: Alright thank you very much that really helped me out a lot!

Comment: @D.John You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Bernoulli's inequality states that
$$(1+h)^n\ge 1+nh$$
when $n\in\Bbb N$ and $h>-1$. Try $h=(x-1)/n$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put $$f(x)=x^\frac 1n$$

$f$ is differentiable at $(0,+\infty)$,
and by MVT

$$f(x)-f(1)=(x-1)f'(c)$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a formulation of *Bernoulli's inequality* which gives a very short proof:
$$\forall y> 0,\quad y^n-1\ge n(y-1)$$

Now the inequality you have to prove can be written as
$$x-1\ge n(\sqrt[n]{x}-1).$$
So just set $\;y=\sqrt[n]{x}$.